# How to detect if a user has signed in to my app using Firebase with Facebook, email, or Google using Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to detect if a user has signed in using Facebook or email, etc...

I found an answer for Android, but I am programming in Swift for iOS and I am not sure how to translate the code entirely.

The android/java code is :

```
for (UserInfo user:FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getProviderData()) {
if (user.getProviderId().equals("facebook.com")) {
System.out.println("User is signed in with Facebook");
  }
}
```

I have tried to translate it, but I can't seem to figure out how to access the values. I keep getting a memory address instead.

Here is my swift code:

```
let authenticatedWith = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.providerData
```

Comment: My swift code above I am pretty sure does that, but I can't access the strings inside. From the documentation, I see that it's stored as an NSArray, but as I said I am not sure how to extract the values. Just using provider on its own will always give the Firebase, because what happens is that the user is authenticated by the third party, then firebase creates a custom ID and that is what is used and everytime the user logs in using any authentication method. If I understand the documentation that is.

Comment: I'm going to answer this properly.

Comment: I did look at that, but as I said currentUser?.providerData always returns Firebase.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/interface_f_i_r_user), `providerData` is an array of `FIRUserInfo` structures.

The (mostly) equivalent Swift code for the Android code you posted looks like this:

```
if let providerData = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.providerData {
    for userInfo in providerData {
        switch userInfo.providerID {
        case "facebook.com":
            print("user is signed in with facebook")
        default:
            print("user is signed in with \(userInfo.providerID)")
    }
}
```

Note that the `providerID` property is also available directly on the `FIRUser` structure returned by the `currentUser` property, so you may be able to just do this:

```
if let providerID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.providerID {
    switch providerID {
    default:
        print("user is signed in with \(providerID)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, Thank you. (The first block of code in this answer)