# Permission denied to set value to Firebase database

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

In my firebase database, I have set the following rule:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am developing iOS app with Firebase. I use Facebook authentication to login to my app, I would like to add user id to database when the login is successful, this is my code:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference()
...
// I got uid 
ref.child("Users").setValue(uid)
```

But I got error:

```
setValue: or removeValue: at /users failed: permission_denied
```

Why?

Comment: Hello Leem you got any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have permission to write a value to `/users`, so the operation is denied.

You **do** have permission to write a value to `/users/$uid`. You're probably trying to do something like this:

```
ref.child("Users").child(uid).setValue(true)
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I add uid to "Users" only for Facebook authenticated user? As I mentioned in my question, the `uid` is the successfully logged in user (Facebook login)

Comment: The code snippet I shared solves the error message you have in your question. if you want to additionally detect whether the user is signed in with Facebook, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39056853/how-to-detect-if-a-user-has-signed-in-to-my-app-using-firebase-with-facebook-em